# How to set Filter in run time ? for gridview in C#, Winforms, DevExpress

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I attach new DataSource and DataSet on Run Time. I set the filter also in the Run Time but it shows error

> Cannot find column [invoice_number]

my code :

```
// Create a data adapter. 
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = 
    new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM gridview", connection);

// Create and fill a dataset. 
DataSet sourceDataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(sourceDataSet);

// Specify the data source for the grid control. 
gridControl1.DataSource = sourceDataSet.Tables[0];

// error show in this line
invoiceBindingSource.Filter = 
    string.Format("invoice_number = '{0}'", textEdit5.Text);
```

but my OrionSystem Access Database has the Column "invoice_number" in the table gridview. What is my error ?

Comment: Did you set data for invoiceBindingSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the filter on the bindingsource, but you set the datasource directly on the grid control.

You must set the datasource on the bindingsource, and then set the grid's datasource to the bindingsource:

```
// Create a data adapter. 
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = 
    new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM gridview", connection);

// Create and fill a dataset. 
DataSet sourceDataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(sourceDataSet);

// Specify the data source for the bindingsource. 
invoiceBindingSource.DataSource = sourceDataSet.Tables[0];

// Specify the data source for the grid control. 
gridControl1.DataSource = invoiceBindingSource;

// error show in this line
invoiceBindingSource.Filter = 
    string.Format("invoice_number = '{0}'", textEdit5.Text);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Or you can always set the GridView.ActiveFilterString property.